# Novice: How to properly set up db connection on zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdo, database-connection, zend-db

I'm pretty new to OOP and Zend. So far I'm trying to set up a db connection. I have this in my application.ini file:

```
resources.db.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "root"
resources.db.params.password = ""
resources.db.params.dbname = "dbtest"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
```

Supposedly I can access the db adapter everywhere with:

```
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
```

The problem is most guides assume you automatically know where to place that, but I honestly have no idea. What I'm doing so far is in my Index.php model I have a method:

```
public function getPosts()
{
 $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts";
 $result = $db->fetchAll($sql);
 return $result;
}
```

With that one query it would be okay, but if I want to create more methods that hold my other queries each time I will have to call $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter() so I'm sure I'm not doing this in an efficient way. I've already tried placing it in various __construct() and init() methods, but it wouldn't work. Where would I add the code without having to call it each time? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way to run your queries would be to create a class for each of your tables that extends `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` which would provide you some handy methods to help you get your stuff from your database.

While using this method you will be able to call your table content through

```
$postsTable = new Model_Db_Tables_Posts() // Assuming you put your class post in the folders models/db/tables/
$posts = $postsTable->fetchAll();
```

for a more specific post you could also fetch it by id using

```
$singlePost = $postsTable->find(1); // Assuming the id of the post you want is 1
```

And then for creating new entries you could go with

```
$data = array('title' => 'Some title', 'content' => 'Some Content') // where the key is the table field and the value is the value you want to insert
$newId = $postsTable->insert($data);
```

And for updating

```
$data = array('title' => 'Some title', 'content' => 'Some Content')
$db = $postsTable->getAdapter();
$where = $db->quoteInto('id = ?', $id); // quoteInto is used to escape unwanted chars in your query, not really usefull for integers, but still a good habit to have
$postsTable->update($data, $where);
```

Hope this helps you a bit, you could find more info in the official ZF doc at http://framework.zend.com/manual/fr/zend.db.table.html and http://framework.zend.com/manual/fr/zend.db.table.row.html

Comment: So instantiating the new class automatically makes a db connection for you? Where would I save my class that extends the Zend_Db_Table_Abstract, sorry once again still really new at this.

Comment: if you have set your default database adapter in your bootstrap, automatically any Zend_Db_Table_Abstract that you extends will use this adapter unless you specify an other adapter to use. Since ZF uses an autoloader to load your class, you just have to make sure that the name reflect the position of the file ie: Model_Db_Tables_Posts() must be located in the folders models/db/tables/posts.php from your application folder (Zend convert the Model to models automatically in the path).

Comment: Thanks, I got it working now, but now I find myself in the same situation as before. Every time I want to call a method that runs a query I have to use: $postsTable = new Model_Db_Tables_Posts(), or is this normal? I figured that you wouldn't want to repeat that every time.

Comment: You just have to call it once in a function/method/controller and you can run multiple queries throught that object. ie: you can load data and then update it without having to instanciate it again, but, yes you have to use it again. But at least you get more closer to a business logic / database logic separation.

Comment: I see... in that case I think I'll stick with the original I was using: $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
Seems to have less setup required, I don't need to create all the extra files. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: As you see fit. Creating those extra files could save you headaches in the long run, since that way all your sql would be isolated from your business logic. Otherwise, if you would like to switch you DB manager, you would have to go throught all your files and edit you sql queries since there is no definitive standard between each database management system.